# Method cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, swing

I have 3 classes; a start class, a kassa class and a kassapaneel class. The kassapaneel is my panel, it is the graphical side if I am correct. In my kassa class I have a method called getSubtotaal, it's extended to my kassapaneel but it doesn't seem to recognize it. Same goes for berekenBTW. And the totaal variable too.

My kassa class:

```
package Opdrachten;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Kassa extends JPanel{
private double subtotaal;
private final double PERCENTAGE_BTW = 19.0;

public void telOp(double bedrag) {
    subtotaal += bedrag;
}

public double getSubtotaal() {
    return subtotaal;
}

public void reset() {
    subtotaal = 0;
}

public double berekenBTW() {
    return subtotaal - berekenSubtotaalExBTW();
}

public double berekenSubtotaalExBTW() {
    return subtotaal / (1 + PERCENTAGE_BTW / 100);
}
}
```

My kassapaneel (panel):

```
package Opdrachten;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Kassapaneel extends Kassa {
private JTextField invoerVak;
  private JTextField subtotaalVak, BTWVak, exBTWVak, totaalVak;
  private JLabel invoerLabel, subtotaalLabel, BTWLabel, exBTWLabel, totaalLabel;
  private JButton totaalKnop, resetKnop;
  private Kassa kassa;



  public Kassapaneel() 
  {
    setLayout( null ); 
    //maak kassa
    kassa = new Kassa();


    //maak knop
    totaalKnop = new JButton("Totaal");
    totaalKnop.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Double subtotaal = kassa.getSubtotaal();
            Double btw = kassa.berekenBTW();
            Double exBtw = subtotaal - btw;

            subtotaalVak.setText(String.valueOf(subtotaal));
            BTWVak.setText(String.valueOf(btw));
            exBTWVak.setText(String.valueOf(exBtw));
        }
    });

    resetKnop = new JButton("Reset");
    resetKnop.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            kassa.reset();
        }
    });

    // Maak de tekstvakken
    invoerVak = new JTextField( 10 );
    invoerVak.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.RIGHT );
    invoerVak.addActionListener( new KnopHandler1() );

    subtotaalVak = new JTextField( 10 );
    subtotaalVak.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.RIGHT );
    subtotaalVak.addActionListener( new KnopHandler1() );
    subtotaalVak.setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );


    BTWVak = new JTextField( 10 );
    BTWVak.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.RIGHT );
    BTWVak.addActionListener( new KnopHandler1() );
    BTWVak.setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );


    exBTWVak = new JTextField( 10 );
    exBTWVak.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.RIGHT );
    exBTWVak.addActionListener( new KnopHandler1() );
    exBTWVak.setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );

    totaalVak = new JTextField( 10 );
    totaalVak.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.RIGHT );
    totaalVak.addActionListener( new KnopHandler1() );
    totaalVak.setBackground( Color.GREEN );




    // Maak de labels
    invoerLabel = new JLabel( "voer bedrag in" );
    subtotaalLabel = new JLabel("Subtotaal");
    BTWLabel = new JLabel ("BTW");
    exBTWLabel = new JLabel ("Totaal ex BTW");
    totaalLabel = new JLabel ("Totaal");


    // Bepaal van alle componenten de plaats en afmeting

    invoerVak.setBounds ( 100,50,120,20 );
    subtotaalVak.setBounds ( 100,80,120,20 );
    BTWVak.setBounds ( 100,110,120,20 );
    exBTWVak.setBounds ( 100,140,120,20 );
    totaalVak.setBounds ( 100,170,120,20 );

    totaalKnop.setBounds ( 230,50,100,20 );
    resetKnop.setBounds ( 230,80,100,20 );

    invoerLabel.setBounds ( 10,50,120,20 );
    subtotaalLabel.setBounds ( 10,80,120,20 );
    BTWLabel.setBounds ( 10,110,120,20 );
    exBTWLabel.setBounds ( 10,140,120,20 );
    totaalLabel.setBounds ( 10,170,120,20 );



    // Voeg de componenten toe aan het paneel
    add (invoerVak);
    add (subtotaalVak);
    add (BTWVak);
    add (exBTWVak);
    add (totaalVak);
    add (totaalKnop);
    add (resetKnop);
    add (invoerLabel);
    add (subtotaalLabel);
    add (BTWLabel);
    add (exBTWLabel);
    add (totaalLabel);

  }


  class KnopHandler1 implements ActionListener 
  {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) 
    {
        String invoer = invoerVak.getText();
        double invoerBedrag = Double.parseDouble (invoer);

        //hiermee stop je het bedrag in het kassasysteem.
        kassa.telOp (invoerBedrag);
        kassa.berekenBTW();
        kassa.berekenSubtotaalExBTW();

        kassa.totaal = (kassa.getSubtotaal + kassa.berekenBTW);            
    }
  }

  class KnopHandler2 implements ActionListener 
  {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) 
    {
        kassa.reset();

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What method cannot be resolved, and where?

Comment: Is it the method that cannot be resolved? I see `kassa.totaal = (kassa.getSubtotaal + kassa.berekenBTW);` with no parenthesis. This would cause an issue. I see no public variable called `totaal` in the `Kasaa` class.

Comment: Moreover, you are extending the Kassa class but you are defining an attribute of class Kassa. Is this a wanted behaviour?

Comment: I am confused with my own code..

Comment: @Lucafraser You have some interesting code. I've noticed a few things strange, like how you create inner classes that extend `ActionListener`, but instead use an anonymous classe for your Reset button. You also extend `Kasaa`, and create a new `Kasaa` object in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt to resolve some of your issues:

I removed the Kasaa object, because the `Kassapaneel extends Kasaa`. That means you'll have access to the protected+ methods and fields within Kasaa. I believe the issue you're experiencing was within the `KnopHandler1` ActionListener. You were attempting to call fields that didn't exist, and they weren't methods because they didn't have the parenthesis at the end.

```
package Opdrachten;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Kassapaneel extends Kassa {
private JTextField invoerVak;
  private JTextField subtotaalVak, BTWVak, exBTWVak, totaalVak;
  private JLabel invoerLabel, subtotaalLabel, BTWLabel, exBTWLabel, totaalLabel;
  private JButton totaalKnop, resetKnop;    

  public Kassapaneel() 
  {
    setLayout( null ); 

    //maak knop
    totaalKnop = new JButton("Totaal");
    totaalKnop.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Double subtotaal = getSubtotaal();
            Double btw = berekenBTW();
            Double exBtw = subtotaal - btw;

            subtotaalVak.setText(String.valueOf(subtotaal));
            BTWVak.setText(String.valueOf(btw));
            exBTWVak.setText(String.valueOf(exBtw));
        }
    });

    resetKnop = new JButton("Reset");
    resetKnop.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            reset();
        }
    });

    // Maak de tekstvakken
    invoerVak = new JTextField( 10 );
    invoerVak.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.RIGHT );
    invoerVak.addActionListener( new KnopHandler1() );

    subtotaalVak = new JTextField( 10 );
    subtotaalVak.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.RIGHT );
    subtotaalVak.addActionListener( new KnopHandler1() );
    subtotaalVak.setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );


    BTWVak = new JTextField( 10 );
    BTWVak.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.RIGHT );
    BTWVak.addActionListener( new KnopHandler1() );
    BTWVak.setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );


    exBTWVak = new JTextField( 10 );
    exBTWVak.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.RIGHT );
    exBTWVak.addActionListener( new KnopHandler1() );
    exBTWVak.setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );

    totaalVak = new JTextField( 10 );
    totaalVak.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.RIGHT );
    totaalVak.addActionListener( new KnopHandler1() );
    totaalVak.setBackground( Color.GREEN );




    // Maak de labels
    invoerLabel = new JLabel( "voer bedrag in" );
    subtotaalLabel = new JLabel("Subtotaal");
    BTWLabel = new JLabel ("BTW");
    exBTWLabel = new JLabel ("Totaal ex BTW");
    totaalLabel = new JLabel ("Totaal");


    // Bepaal van alle componenten de plaats en afmeting

    invoerVak.setBounds ( 100,50,120,20 );
    subtotaalVak.setBounds ( 100,80,120,20 );
    BTWVak.setBounds ( 100,110,120,20 );
    exBTWVak.setBounds ( 100,140,120,20 );
    totaalVak.setBounds ( 100,170,120,20 );

    totaalKnop.setBounds ( 230,50,100,20 );
    resetKnop.setBounds ( 230,80,100,20 );

    invoerLabel.setBounds ( 10,50,120,20 );
    subtotaalLabel.setBounds ( 10,80,120,20 );
    BTWLabel.setBounds ( 10,110,120,20 );
    exBTWLabel.setBounds ( 10,140,120,20 );
    totaalLabel.setBounds ( 10,170,120,20 );



    // Voeg de componenten toe aan het paneel
    add (invoerVak);
    add (subtotaalVak);
    add (BTWVak);
    add (exBTWVak);
    add (totaalVak);
    add (totaalKnop);
    add (resetKnop);
    add (invoerLabel);
    add (subtotaalLabel);
    add (BTWLabel);
    add (exBTWLabel);
    add (totaalLabel);

  }


  class KnopHandler1 implements ActionListener 
  {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) 
    {
        String invoer = invoerVak.getText();
        double invoerBedrag = Double.parseDouble (invoer);

        //hiermee stop je het bedrag in het kassasysteem.
        telOp (invoerBedrag);
        berekenBTW();
        berekenSubtotaalExBTW();

        double totaal = (getSubtotaal() + berekenBTW()); //<--- Issue here.
        System.out.println("Totaal == " + totaal);
    }
  }

  class KnopHandler2 implements ActionListener 
  {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) 
    {
        reset();
    }
  }

public static void main(String...banana)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(new Kassapaneel());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
}

}
```

To elaborate on the comment `//<--- Issue here`, you were calling `kassa.getSubtotaal`. I changed this to `getSubtotaal()`. The former suggests that there's a field within the `Kasaa` class -- Eg: `public double getSubtotal = 0;` This doesn't exist, it is instead a method, so you should have been calling `kassa.getSubtotaal()` with the `()` at the end. In addition to this, you were attempting to set a variable `kasaa.total` where there is no resemblance of this method or variable within the `Kasaa` class.

Comment: It still doesn't work, what is the problem right now? And what is the "issue here."?

Comment: @Lucafraser The purpose of this code was to resolve your issue with the `Method cannot be resolved or is not a field` issue. If you have further issues beyond this, they would be beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: @Lucafraser I see now that the functionality of the buttons will work incorrectly because you're not getting the values from the `JTextFields`, In your ActionListener, you should be calling  `Double.parseDouble(subtotaalVak.getText());`